# Running a Google Sheets App script function from an HTML page with form values returned

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I'm trying to return the values that a user enters into a form on a webpage in a google app script to a function and then notify the user with a response.

Here is my app script

```
function onOpen() {
   openLogin();
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     .createMenu('Dialog')
     .addItem('Open', 'openLogin')
     .addToUi()
}

function openLogin() {
   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Login Form');
}

function checkLogin() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello, world!'); 
}
```

I'm trying to get checkLogin to fire off. Here is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <form>    
    First name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="user_name"><br><br>
    Last name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="password" name="user_password"><br><br>
    Staff or Student?
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="staff" value="staff" checked> Staff<br>
    <input type="radio" name="student" value="student"> Student<br>
    <br><br>

    <input type="button" value="OK"
    onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

    <input type="button" value="Close"
    onclick="google.script.run.checkLogin()" />

  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake,
I had the OK and Close function calls mixed up. It should have been

```
<input type="button" value="OK"
onclick="google.script.run.checkLogin()" />

<input type="button" value="Close"
onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```